# How to detect unused maven dependencies

Tags: java, dependencies, maven

I have a maven project that was generated by Spring Roo. Now I am not sure whether I need all of its dependencies.

Is there a tool to automate the process of detecting stale dependencies?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [Maven Dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/) should be able to help, especially the [analyze](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-mojo.html) options.

Comment: Mind that this plugin also generates libraries that are used in the project. I found a few libraries that are used during test goal but maven prints them out as unused.